# ServiceStack.Text in .NET not deserializing nested datetime

Tags: datetime, xamarin, deserialization, servicestack-text

I am talking to a web service from Xamarin.  It is sending dates down over the wire in JSON, in ISO-8601 format, like this:

"2016-05-13T16:02:47.480-07:00"

If I try to deserialize just a single date, it works fine.  But when the DateTime is a member of class, it does not work.  No error is given.  Here is some example code:

```
using ServiceStack.Text;

class TestDate {
   public DateTime  testDate;
}

void Test() {
    JsConfig.DateHandler = JsonDateHandler.ISO8601; 

    // this works just fine:
    String dateString = "2016-05-13T16:02:47.480-07:00";
    DateTime theDate = dateString.FromJson<DateTime> ();

    // this does not deserialize
    String testStr = "{\"testDate\":\"2016-05-13T16:02:51.923-07:00\"}";
    TestDate tester = testStr.FromJson<TestDate> ();
}
```

Any ideas?  I don't see any error, just get a new TestDate object without the date being set.

Answer (score 0):

ServiceStack Text Serializer does serialize as expected:

```
JsConfig.DateHandler = ServiceStack.Text.DateHandler.ISO8601;

var dto = new TestDate { testDate = new DateTime(2016, 05, 13, 16, 02, 47, 480) };
var json = dto.ToJson();
json.Print(); //= {"testDate":"2016-05-13T16:02:47.4800000"}
```

and deserializes correctly:

```
var fromJson = json.FromJson<TestDate>();
Assert.That(fromJson.testDate, Is.EqualTo(dto.testDate)); //= true
```

Comment: Ok i don't have control over the Web service, any ideas for the best way to parse it? Also, how come it works with a single date?

Comment: @DaveVronay It parses by default without changing the DateHandler also it looks like you're using a very old version of ServiceStack.Text where `JsonDateHandler` type no longer exists.

Comment: Also I just checked the page you linked and it seems that the ISO 8601 does support time zones...  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators

Comment: @DaveVronay Yeah apologies quick misread of docs, BTW this also works in the latest version of ServiceStack.Text. But you have an issue with your DTO, only **public properties** are serialized by default, otherwise you need to add `JsConfig.IncludePublicFields = true`